# apache.poi HSSFCell getNumericCellValue incorrect read

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssf

I read numeric values from excel using apache.poi.

```
hssfCell.getNumericCellValue()
```

But here is example of excel file where the result is wrong.

[Example of excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/twif5qnwuph7ksl/Example.xls?dl=0)

The correct result for cell N14 is 11,115 (or 11,12 with excel formatting). But hssfCell.getNumericCellValue() get result 11.114999999999998.

It's formula cell, so I can use dateFormatter, then result is 11,11.

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(importFile));
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(wb);
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
formulaEvaluator.evaluate(hssfCell);
dataFormatter.formatCellValue(hssfCell, formulaEvaluator);
```

Excel shows me 11,12. How can I get this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);      
decimalFormat.format(hssfCell.getNumericCellValue());
```

The problem is that the precision is hard-code. If you will only use 2 decimal places, this solution will work fine.